# Initializing object with names from array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

```cs
internal class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, string city)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.LastName = lastname;
        this.City = city;

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName;
        return LastName;
        return City;
    }
}
```

here is a class Person-and this is code for making objects from class

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] mychars = new char[] { ' ','.', '/' };

    string text = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow ";

    foreach (var s in text.Split(mychars))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Person[] persons = new Person[text.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        persons[0] = new Person("", "", "");
        persons[1] = new Person("", "", "");
        persons[2] = new Person("", "", "");
    }
    foreach(var person in persons)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName + "" + person.LastName + "" +person.City);
    }
}
```

(I know where is mistake ,but because of little experience I don`t know how to fix it)assignment was about to get all names ,last names and cities,put that in Person[]array, go through that array and at the end get this in console:

Mary Davidson Paris

Michael Barton Krakow

Ivan Perkinson Berlin

Comment: Your `ToString` should be something like `return FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + City;` and then in your loop just print that object, `Console.WriteLine(person);` On another note look into [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-6.0) to concatenate values.

Comment: You need to actually cache the splits to a variable and use them. Right now you aren't doing anything with the string split except for console logging it. All your `Person` objects are being initialized with empty strings, you want to initialize them with the values from the string splits. Your looping over the length of the string and creating 3 `Person`s for each character. You will end up with 3x the # of characters in the string `Person`s, when you only want 3 total i believe?

Comment: `ToString` returns at the first return-statement and ignores the other ones because the function can return only once. You should get a warning "unreachable code detected".

Comment: Input format is not very good. What should input look like for person Sacha Baron Cohen  from New York (having a lot of spaces there)?

Answer (score 1):

Implemented the comments for you. Look at ToString() and the way that the person object is created.

```
public static void Main()
{
    char[] mychars = new char[] { ' ','.', '/' };

    string text = " John.Davidson/Belgrade Michael.Barton/Krakow Ivan.Perkinson/Moscow ";

    var people = new List<Person>();
    var arr = text.Split(mychars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    
    for(var i = 0; i< arr.Length; i+=3)
    {
        people.Add(new Person(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]));
    }
    
    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person);
    }
}

internal class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public Person(string firstname, string lastname, string city)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.LastName = lastname;
        this.City = city;

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + City;
    }
}
```